# Pause game OnSteamVR Overlay Active

Tags: c++, virtual-reality, steam, unreal-engine4

I've been following this guide that covers pause with Steam Overlay:

https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Pause_Game_On_Steam_Overlay_Active

It works very well. However I cannot find any way to make it work with SteamVR Overlay. My code is almost identical except for class names and adding delegate for broadcasting results. Any idea how can i make it work? I thought that it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly the same, I'm afraid. To interact with SteamVR, you need to use the [OpenVR API](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/d35c04ca3d7ddb762afa4a1c6c4a9d5de992cda7/headers/openvr.h). It looks like there's a function called ShouldApplicationPause() which does what you want; I'm assuming you'd call it once per frame to see if you ought to pause.